# Выборка даных из связаных таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть шесть таблиц у которых внешний ключ указывает на таблицу Серийный номер(на поле ID) в кторой есть серийный номер и его айди. В шести таблицах есть айди серийного номера из таблицы серийный номер и даты (Колонка date)

как в одном запросе выбрать из всех таблиц даты которые соответсвтуют нужной и серийный номер на который ссылаемся по ID

---

так не хочет работать:

```
SELECT sent428.date, sent613.date, SerialNumb.Serial
FROM sent428, sent613
INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID;
INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID;
```

Comment: В вопросе вы говорите, что у вас 6 таблиц, а в примере у вас 3 таблицы. Как это понимать?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sent428.date,SerialNumb.Serial
FROM sent428
  INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT sent613.date,SerialNumb.Serial
FROM sent613
  INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
```

И ещё: не надо смешивать в одном запросе явные и неявные JOIN. В некоторых СУБД это вообще запрещено, в других хотя и разрешено, но всё равно лучше так не делать: такой запрос неудобен для понимания.

Comment: "SELECT sent428.date as 'Полученые' ,SerialNumb.Serial as 'Серийный номер' "
                   + "FROM sent428 "
                   + "INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent428.ID_Serial = SerialNumb.ID "
                   + "where date = '" + date + "'"
                    +"UNION ALL "
                    + "SELECT post428.date as 'Полученые' ,SerialNumb.Serial as 'Серийный номер' "
                    + "FROM post428 "
                    + "INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON post428.ID_Serial = SerialNumb.ID "
                    + "where date = '"+ date +"'"; ;

Comment: Как написать что бы выводило не в два столбца а в разные с разных таблиц в разные

Comment: vikolyada ответил же. У него даты из разных таблиц в разных столбцах.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужны даты из всех шести таблиц в одной строке, то необходимо к основной таблице серийных номеров `SerialNumb` соединять остальные. Если у вас для каждой записи в `SerialNumb` обязательно существует записи в каждой связанной таблице, то следует соединять посредством `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT SerialNumb.Serial, sent428.date, sent613.date
FROM SerialNumb
INNER JOIN sent428 ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
INNER JOIN sent613 ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID;
```

В случае если связанная запись может отсутствовать в таблицах используйте `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT SerialNumb.Serial, sent428.date, sent613.date
FROM SerialNumb
LEFT JOIN sent428 ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
LEFT JOIN sent613 ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID;
```

Comment: А если мне из каждой таблицы  нужно в отдельный столбик ?

Comment: Тут как раз отдельные столбцы — `sent428.date, sent613.date`

Comment: 'SELECT sent428.date, SerialNumb.Serial
FROM sent428
  INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT sent613.date,SerialNumb.Serial
FROM sent613
  INNER JOIN SerialNumb ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID'                такой код выводит только два столбца это date  serial

Comment: как добавить условие ?

Comment: Нужно, добавить ключевое слово `WHERE`.

Comment: если мне например нужно вывести с каждой таблицы где одинаковая дата

Comment: Не понятно, что значит «где одинаковая дата»

Comment: в каждой таблице у меня столбец с датой  мне нужно что бы со всех таблиц выбралось где дата например 19.12.2017  то есть where Table.date ='19.12.2017' как выборку со всех сделать ?

Comment: Обновите вопрос и покажите, что конкретно вы хотите сделать и какие данные у вас есть.

Comment: 'SELECT SerialNumb.Serial, sent428.date, sent613.date
FROM SerialNumb

RIGHT JOIN sent428 ON sent428.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID 
Where sent428.date='12.12.1978'
Right JOIN sent613 ON sent613.ID_Serial=SerialNumb.ID
Where sent613.date='12.12.1978';'

Comment: Читайте документацию `WHERE` используется один раз в запросе.

Comment: SELECT post428.date, post613.date
 from post428, post613 
where post428.ID_User=1 or post613.ID_User=1                                             выдает 500 записей хотя у меня только по одной в каждой таблице как быть?

Comment: Читайте документацию.